# Drupal 7 Recaptcha not showing in mobile devices

Tags: drupal-7, recaptcha

I have a recaptcha module, it is appearing well on desktop, when i accessed the same on mobile, i cant find it there.

I have enabled it asn registered it on google re-captcha to get the private and public key.

I have found out it is because the browser is outdated, in such case, i want the match captcha to replace the recaptcha in the form.
I have set the math captcha as my default captcha at admin/people/captcha

Answer (score 0):

What is your specific question?

Instead of using recaptcha, have you considered honeypot?  It is far more a11y friendly and has done a great job blocking spam on our servers.